# Pycharm is not making changes to the file system

Tags: python, macos, file, filesystems, pycharm

I'm working on a Django project with Pycharm. As you can see from the screenshot, I have an HTML file named `base_generic.html` and a directory called `blog/` at
`~/PycharmProjects/diyblog/templates/`.

[image]

However, executing `ls ~/PycharmProjects/diyblog/templates/` in the terminal prints nothing, which means this file does not exist in the actual file system.

I've noticed that its file name is in green, presumably because it's a newly-created file. I'm using git as my VCS, does this matter? Do I have to `git add -A` and/or `git commit -m 'ignore me -- making change to the file system'` to get the changes applied to the file system?

This is the content of `Version Control: Console`

```
12:13:27.760: [diyblog] git -c core.quotepath=false rm --ignore-unmatch --cached -- .idea/inspectionProfiles/profiles_settings.xml
12:13:35.439: [diyblog] git -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors -- .idea/vcs.xml
20:27:02.649: [diyblog] git -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors -- .idea/dataSources.xml
21:09:40.354: [diyblog] git -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors -- templates/base_generic.html
21:13:52.903: [diyblog] git -c core.quotepath=false rm --ignore-unmatch --cached -- templates/base_generic.html
21:13:53.015: [diyblog] git -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors -- blog/template/base_generic.html
21:15:23.659: [diyblog] git -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors -- blog/template/blog/blog_list.html
21:21:52.913: [diyblog] git -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors -- blog/template/blog/blogger_list.html
21:26:17.569: [diyblog] git -c core.quotepath=false rm --ignore-unmatch --cached -- blog/template/blog/blog_list.html blog/template/blog/blogger_list.html blog/template/base_generic.html
21:26:17.664: [diyblog] git -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors -- blog/templates/blog/blog_list.html blog/templates/blog/blogger_list.html blog/templates/base_generic.html
```

Here is the about information, in case it's relevant

```
Pycharm PyCharm 2017.1
Build #PY-171.3780.115, built on March 24, 2017
Licensed to sun qingyao
Subscription is active until December 7, 2017
For educational use only.
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b13 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.3
```

Comment: Looks like your file is not in `~/PycharmProjects/diyblog/templates/` but `~/PycharmProjects/diyblog/blog/templates/blog/`.

Comment: @Matthias Yes you're right. They are at `~/PycharmProjects/diyblog/blog/templates/blog/`... ***STUPID ME!!!***

Comment: and the colors on the names are GIT-related.

Comment: Be careful! I think you are writting the path wrong and your file is not in "~/PycharmProjects/diyblog/templates/"! Ups! @Matthias had already said that! Sorry